# Complex replacement in gVim

Tags: vim

I have been a terrible person as of late when it comes to Minecraft. I have over-modded it to the point that I need to completely re-write the IDs of them all.
The only problem is that... It'll take about a couple of hours jut to re-write them ONCE, not to mention if any of them collide with the original game. So, in order to save time, I figured I'd use Vim, but after reading through several of the helpful posts on here, I still only know a minimal amount about the replacement feature/command. Here's what I'm trying to do:
Replace this

```
I:exampleModnamePath.id=16389
I:exampleModnamePat2.id=19657
```

Etc.

With this

```
I:exampleModnamePath.id=20000
I:exampleModnamePath.id=20001
```

Etc.

This continues for a while, and to those who answer, could you please inform me of how it works, so I don't have to ask these questions all the time?

Answer (score 1):

For your perusal:

```
:let g:num = 1
:g/\.id=\d\+$/exec 's!\.id=\d\+$!.id='.g:num.'! | let g:num=g:num+1'
```

This is slightly simplified version of my code for (re)numbering chapters in the ebooks.

Idea in a nutshell: use `:g` to run something over affected lines; use `:exec` to generate/run new substitution command AND increment the counter. Tried it once and was surprised to find that the trick worked. Was inspired by my previous toying with `:g//s///` combo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the rule you are using to choose which number to use for replacement but if all you need
is just a new number that doesn't collide with previous ones you could try just replacing the first digit
with something in a range not used. Something like replacing 16389 with 76389

To do that you could use this `:s/Path.id=.\(.*\)/Path.id=7\1`

That would search for the string Path.id= followed by a single character and then a group of more characters.
I will replace it with the string Path.id=7 and the group previously selected.

You could make it more selectiv adding letters before Path.id to match only certain types of paths.